# 'onRequestPermissionsResult' overrides nothing

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to implement a verfication on permission result for my Activity:

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
   //...
   override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String?>?, grantResults: IntArray) {
```

But I get

```
MainActivity.kt: (325, 5): 'onRequestPermissionsResult' overrides nothing
```

According to https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback, activity extends this interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the signature of the `onRequestPermissionsResult` function of `FlutterActivity` that extends `Activity`. Note how the permissions parameter differs from your override declaration ?

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull
                                       String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull
                                       int[] grantResults)
```

As you can see the parameters are annotated `@NonNull` which means you can't use the nullable operator and override this as `..., permissions: Array<String?>?, ...`